# How can I copy a scheduled task from a dead Windows to new Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

My old computer died (hardware fault) and I had to reinstall everything on a new machine. All harddisks are intact and the old system disk is available as F: in my new machine.

In the old system I had a scheduled task that would run a simple batch file on system startup or possibly on login. I have no detailed notes about how I set it up so would prefer to copy it from the old "dead" Windows installation.

Is there any way that this can be done? I can't boot up the old Windows installation to export the task or anything, but as I mentioned I do have access to the entire disk where it resides.

Both installations are Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are two directories within which you might find a scheduled task definition or log:

```
c:\windows\tasks 
c:\windows\system32\tasks
```

That said, depending on the task, you may or may not have difficulties using the configured task on another computer. Some tasks may contain system-specific information, and others may be in formats that cannot be opened for editing (3rd party programs often ship .job files). Carefully review the definition before attempting to run the imported tasks.

Good luck.

Comment: Found in the second folder `C:\Windows\system32\Tasks` and successfully imported. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, perhaps I should mention, in case it helps anyone, that the files in that folder are XML files, but without the XML file extension.

Answer (score 19):

Tasks are normally stored in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` (as xml files).
You should be able to import from there