# Where are Schedule Tasks stored?

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

When we create a scheduled task in Windows 10 with `schtasks.exe`, which files/databases/registry entries are being modified? For example, are the tasks seen with `schtasks.exe /query` accessible in a file somewhere on the OS?

Comment: This may help: https://superuser.com/questions/950458/how-can-i-copy-a-scheduled-task-from-a-dead-windows-to-new-windows/950466#950466

Answer (score 2):

Task Scheduler 1.0 API uses

> C:\Windows\Tasks

folder for create and enumerate tasks , while

Task Scheduler 2.0 API uses

> C:\Windows\System32\Tasks

to create and enumerate tasks